Horror movie about a newlywed couple on the road who buried a man
Can anyone help me? I can't find one horror movie!
It's about a couple which just get married and they are maybe on honeymoon, I'm not sure. Then they are going on Route 66 I think in a cadillac maybe. I think that they then got lost and an almost dead men got in their car.
I think that movie is from 2009 or 2011. That couple met a night before they got married or something like that. They buried the "almost dead man". The man realized that he left his watch at that place. When they come back for it, the body wasn't there. At the end of the movie they were escaping from the police and then they crashed. The weather in the movie was very hot.
Sorry for my bad English.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Damn near impossible with the details you've provided. Mr. Cody is correct, if you add any and all technical details this could help a lot. I have more than a few movies in mind but I cannot attempt to answer unless I can rule some of them out. An approximate year would help a lot. What were the productions values like? Was this a cinema feature or a 'B-movie'?

I think that movie is from 2009 or 2011
That couple met night before they got married or something like that
At the end of movie they were escaping from the police and then they crashed
Couple buried "almost dead men".  Men realized that he left his watch at that place. When they come back for it, body wasn't there.
Weather in movie was very hot @Dannie

The thriller Dark Country from 2009.

A couple en route from Las Vegas are forced to deal with a body out in the desert making their honeymoon one hellish ride.

They come across an injured man in the road who attacks the husband; they fight and the man dies. The husband buries him but later realizes he left his watch behind. Here's the trailer:




You're a machine, Walt.  :oD

Yeah! That's it.
Thank you very much!

@JohnnyBones Well, it's a good thing more details came in. I never would've recognized it otherwise!

I know there's nothing new under the sun, but I'm amused at how this is similar to Christopher Pike's Chain Letter where a set of kids bury a man they hit with their car and accidentally leave behind a ring.
